# Calculating total annual quantity of CO, particulate matter, NOx and SOx

Tags: air, emissions

I am working on something, for that i need to calculate total annual quantities of CO, particulate matter, NOx and SOx for stationary sources. meters are not installed on emission sources. Can anyone please tell me what basic data i need to calculate quantities?

Comment: So base it on the input - if you burn 100 litres of fuel then you can estimate the emissions of the exhaust. Obviously the design,k condition etc of the engine will affect that.

Comment: CEMS (continuous emission monitors) for SOX, NOX, CO for stationary sources have been in-use for probably 4 decades in the US and are now required  worldwide.   Solid particulate emissions are not that easily measured but there are techniques to obtain that data continuously.  Every stationary source > 250 million BTU/hr was monitored initially but now that limit has been lowered to include nearly all devices.  Your statement "meters are not installed on emission sources" shows no research into your question.  Data is available for thousands of sources. Put in some effort and peruse.